# 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://storage.scrapinghub.com/collections

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, zyte

When I run a spider in Scrapy Cloud Projects I get this error:
401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://storage.scrapinghub.com/collections/569447/s/casti

Do you have any idea why?

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw1aD.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGX9H.png)

Comment: Are you providing the correct authorization credentials?

Comment: I am kind of a beginner, can you tell me where and how I can check that?

Comment: I don't know anything about this API. But don't you know whether you created an account and put the credentials into your calls to the API?

Comment: I'm assuming that it's not a public API, which is why you got a "Not authorized" error.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am assuming you have a paid or trial subscription with Zyte.

I had a similar issue with Article Extraction. Turns out I was using the wrong API Key. I was using the one under Account Settings --> API Key. That is not the right one.

Once you log in to zyte.com, you will land on your dashboard page. If you do not see the "Tools" panel on the left, you will need to click the hamburger icon (3 horizontal lines) on the top left and the Tools Panel comes into view.

In my case where my plan includes Extraction, I found the key inside the "Automatic Extraction" section. Depending on your subscription, the section where you find the key may vary (likely under "Scrapy Cloud" if I am reading your email correctly).

Let us know if that works.